# Is it possible to have multiple sites with SSL on the same server pointing to different ports?

Tags: nginx, port

I want to consolidate a couple sites I have to one server. I know that with nginx I can have a Node.js app running on a port and use nginx to make that port point to the domain name (or vice versa).

I want to know if it is possible to have each site in its own folder and/or running on different ports and have each site enabled with SSL, on nginx.

EDIT: Here's an example of what I did to get multiple sites working on the same server, with an A+ rating from SSL Labs.

```
##
# site A / 3001
##

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.tld;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*) https://$host$request_uri permanent;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.tld;
    root /var/www/domain/public;

    index index.html;
    access_log off;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_key sfs$request_uri$scheme;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html)$ {
        expires 30d;
        root /var/www/domain;
    }
}



##
# site B / 3002
##

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain2.tld;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*) https://$host$request_uri permanent;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain2.tld;
    root /var/www/domain2/public;

    index index.html;
    access_log off;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.tld/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.tld/dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_key sfs$request_uri$scheme;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html)$ {
        expires 30d;
        root /var/www/domain2/public;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone else, it took some trial and error getting this right.

Comment: Haha, I'll never understand drive-by downvotes on SE sites. Welp. 
¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Downvotes without comment can be assumed to be for one of the reasons listed in the downvote arrow hover text.

Comment: And yet, someone actually answered my question which led me to finding a solution and hopefully, me adding the solution to my question helped countless others who would otherwise be deterred from trying something new due to lack of feedback. Fortunately, helpful people *do* exist on SE sites and I'm grateful for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, nginx can do it.

You configure each site in its own virtual host with a `server` block, where you configure `server_name` and SSL certificate parameters. Then you use `proxy_pass` directive to make the request go to the backend for that particular site.

Each virtual host can have its own document root where the resources for that virtual host are served from.

Comment: Oh sweet! I wasn't sure if the SSL parameters had to be in the `location` section inside `server` blocks. Thanks! I'll update my post with my finished code later but I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, it's pretty cool that I can do this! (: